# What's an intuitive explanation of the Equal Error Rate, and how to compute it in from a ROC?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, roc, threshold, type-i-and-ii-errors

I am selecting the operating point in ROC curves using EER.
From a visual perspective (see the figure), know it's the point of intersection of the ROC with the descending diagonal.

[image]

1. What is the **formula** to compute the EER?
2. What is the **threshold** at which the classifier would work?

can you also provide some reference, please?

Comment: Equal error rate is only used when the cost of misclassification for both classes in a two class classification problems are considered as being equally bad,

Comment: I'm considering what you mentioned